# Can not show webcam from openCV on Hololens

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm the beginner of programming and openCV. I have to build my own library based on OpenCV and use it on Hololens.
I have a very short time to work on it.  So I have started with many samples from many websites.
I can build the library  and use it in Unity from the sample but I cannot show it on hololens

Now, I'm trying to show webcam like this sample on the hololens. [https://youtube.com/watch?v=vUviuj8KcQM&t=781s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vUviuj8KcQM&t=781s) 
It showed on unity but It didn't show on hololens. Just the cube showed on the hololens.

I think I have to write the script to show this webcam texture from openCV on Hololens but I have no idea. It's very complicated for me.

I would like to ask how to show this webcam texture from openCV on Hololens?
I would like to ask your suggestion where should I start to learn OpenCV, C++, C# and Unity + hololens in short time.

Sorry for my poor English and programming.

Comment: typically such devices have their own SDK with functions to call and so e code samples which show how to use them.

Comment: @Micka Thank you very much for your reply.  Do you mean this one?
https://github.com/VulcanTechnologies/HoloLensCameraStream